# Libvirt qemu changing hardware identifiers?

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt, virt-manager

I am having a strange problem that I just cannot figure out. I have a Windows 7 virtual machine that was originally a physical machine that was demoted to a VM awhile ago. I used to boot it with

```
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -vga std -m 4G -smp cores=4 /path/to/image
```

It did change my hardware information enough to trigger any Windows activation. I recently started using libvirt and virt-manager. Everything went smoothly until I got down to importing this Windows machine. Once I finally got it to boot, it triggered the Windows activation nonsense.

I took screenshots of the reported hardware specs (msinfo32), shut down, then booted back up with the non-problematic command, and compared the reported hardware. Everything looked the same. So I started playing around with WMIC to see if I could get more detailed information. The only thing I noticed was that the cpu ProcessorID field was different across the two boots. I tried all sorts of tweaks to my configuration (primarily, the cpu parameters (match='exact', mode='host-model', mode='host-passthrough', etc)) using `virsh edit machinename`, but to no avail.

Using ps, I can see libvirt is running the following command (split into multiple lines for readability):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name win7 -S \
-machine pc-i440fx-trusty,accel=kvm,usb=off -m 4096 \ 
-realtime mlock=off -smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threads=1 \
-uuid 71ca9116-a4a1-b799-dab5-01a483bce024 \
-no-user-config -nodefaults \
-chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var /lib/libvirt/qemu/win7.monitor,server,nowait \
-mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control \
-rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -boot strict=on \
-device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 \
-drive file=/media/paul/VirtualMachines/win7.vmdk,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,format=vmdk \
-device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1 \
-netdev tap,fd=25,id=hostnet0 \
-device \
    rtl8139, \
    netdev=hostnet0, \
    id=net0, \
    mac=52:54:00:bf:2c:b2,bus=pci.0, \
    addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 \
-device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 \
-device usb-tablet,id=input0 -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 \
-device VGA,id=video0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 \
-device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 \
-device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 \
-device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5
```

Here is my config file: http://pastebin.com/0e2Mf4RE

I can still boot with the simple command and there is no problem. The libvirt qemu command must have changed something about how my hardware is reported to the guest machine. I noticed parameters that look like they may be setting a mac address and hard drive uuid, but that should not matter. I am pretty sure that Windows hardware locking is primarily based on a combination of motherboard and/or cpu.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I tried running the qemu command that libvirt was running above directly, removing arguments until it would boot, and then until Windows showed it was activated. It appears that the `-uuid` caused the problem. I am not sure as to why. I thought the uuid argument was just for the security profile (in my case, AppArmor), but it appears to also change some hardware identifier on the guest?

On the successful boot, I ran `wmic csproduct get uuid` in Windows, copied it, and shutdown. Then I did the following:

```
virsh dumpxml win7 > win7.xml
virsh undefine win7
[Edited win7.xml -> changed uuid to match the one I copied]
virsh define win7.xml
```

I opened up virt-manager and booted. It worked! Looks like uuid sets the motherboard serial number? Interestingly, mine was a string of 0's (apparently, a lot of boards don't report a uuid), so it wasn't really unique, making this whole adventure pretty silly.

I did not post this as an answer because I am not sure why this worked (I just hacked around until it worked and I am making assumptions above). Maybe someone more knowledgeable on the subject can post a better answer?

Comment: Did you spoof the MAC address of the virtual network card so that it is the same as the MAC address of the physical network card the OS had previously? I think I remember once avoiding activation this way.

Comment: @Lonniebiz Just tried it. Unfortunately, no change.

Comment: nowadays you may need to `undefine --nvram` if you receive an error `cannot undefine domain with nvram`